# WPF - Creating a custom control from ButtonBase - Inherited Class still abstract?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance, abstract

I have a custom control in WPF called "JButton" I've inherited from ButtonBase and I've put it in my MainWindow and I'm getting the error "The type JButton is abstract and I'm not sure why.  I'm not even sure how to tell from Windows documentation which methods are abstract and I need to provide implementations for.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationJ.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:project="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationJ"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="1000">
<DockPanel>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="27"    Background="White" BorderBrush="Black">
        <TextBlock Margin="2">

        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="27" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
    </Border>
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,1,0" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="White" Padding="2">
            <Border BorderBrush="#FFBBBBBB" BorderThickness="2">
                <TextBox Margin="2" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    Text Text Text Text text Text Text Text Text
                </TextBox>
            </Border>
        </Border>
        <project:JButton/>


    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
</Window>
```

JButton.xaml

```
<ButtonBase
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 x:Class="WpfApplicationJ.JButton">
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="#FF34F6FF" >

</Border>
</ButtonBase>
```

JButton.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApplicationJ
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for JButton.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class JButton : ButtonBase
{


    public JButton()
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Works for me. However, the JButton constructor is at least missing an `InitializeComponent()` call. You should probably just re-style the existing Button control. See the [Control Authoring Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: InitializeComponent() was giving me a weird error before, but it seems to work now and has fixed it.  I know customizing the Button control would be easier but I just want to take the scenic route to understand WPF better.